# How do I run pgadmin in a web browser by default?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm running pgadmin 5.4 on macOS Big Sur. When I open the application, pgadmin launches in Desktop Mode, as a standalone app.

My goal is to force pgadmin to run within a browser instead, but I'm having trouble finding out how to do this, either as a one-off instance, or as a default (which is my goal).

**What I've Tried:**

I've already looked thru File > Preferences, along with Runtime > Configure.

I've also looked at the Desktop Deployment docs.

None of these solutions have pointed me to an obvious answer and currently I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The closest I've come to a solution thus far is to simply install an older version of pgadmin with this default behavior included (version 4.x will do the trick). Not ideal however, and if anyone has a better solution please share